# Sticky footer acting weird

Tags: html, css, position, sticky-footer

I have made a sticky footer for my website, but it doesnt act like i want i to.
I want it to be totally at the bottom, always depending on the length of the content. Instead it is always present on screen, as it is. Can anyone help me ?

[This site](http://www.thomasteilmann.dk/powerdisco)

footer css:

```
#footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
clear: both;
background-image: url("../images/footer_pattern.png");
```

}

Comment: Would it still be sticky if it wasn't always present at the screen?

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I want it to be pushed down by the content of the page. On smaller screens it would be better that way, so that they can see more content without scrolling. I ofcourse will have a min-height on my content, so i can minimum be at the bottom. Right know, its like my content goes through the footer. Not intended.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a sticky footer at all, you want a normal footer

Comment: This website doesn't render correctly on iOS, footer is about 25px too far right, header is 1px too large vertically and jumps on scrolling. But to help with your question, is the footer outside the content or content containing divs?

Comment: the footer is outside the content, and the content is a div, containing divs. iOS, is that the mobile os or the one on their computers?

Comment: iOS iPad/iPhone/iPod touch. iMac uses safari (as default). You'll need some CSS media queries to sort that out. You just want a normal footer then. Can you post your #footer CSS and I'll clean it up for you.

Comment: Footer css added. Thx for quick respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#footer{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
clear: both;
background-image: url("../images/footer_pattern.png");
display: block;
margin-top: 0px;
//if contains children add overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I can't say I'm 100% certain of what you're actually trying to achieve, but I'm guessing you're trying to fix the div to the bottom of the main content div and the position fixed has thrown you out a bit. If you fix the position it won't grow with the content, it'll stay at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah i see that now actually. It doesnt work properly like this. I think the problem is that my content is position absolute? is there a workaround on this? im just gonna post my whole css file.

Comment: It's also worth noting that for the footer and content to line up you need to make sure there is no margins pushing them apart.

Comment: You don't need to absolute position your content, probably why it gets thrown out on iPad. Just wrap the entire page in a div with the width dimensions you want then add margin: 0 auto; and it'll centre it for you.

Comment: yeah ofc. Sorry for the time between replies. I am cooking dinner while doing this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15006/discussion-between-thomas-teilmann-and-tom)

Comment: Yeah your wrapper. Or you could put it on container divs for header, content and footer. Either way, that's all you need, it'll line up perfectly without using positioning and using margin: 0 auto on the main wrapper and the CSS for your footer as above.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but if I understand correctly I think what you are looking for is position:relative.

```
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
```

what this does is it adds a specified amount of space (10px) in between the element and the next relative parent element. Good Luck!

Comment: on what component should that be put? and thx for the answer btw :)

Comment: On your #footer div, but I don't think this is going to help for what you want.