# Sticky footer not sticking to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I seem to have a problem with the footer on my website. Basically its not sticking to the bottom of my page, but sticking to the bottom of my div, called main. Can anyone help me with this?

If you zoom out on the webpage you will see the problem :)

[this site](http://www.thomasteilmann.dk/powerdisco)

Im not pasting in the code, cause its a lot of php includes and such. Hope it's okay. :)

footer css:

```
#footer{
width: 100%;
float: left;
height: 70px;
bottom: 0;
clear: both;
background-image: url("../images/footer_pattern.png");
display: block;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sticky footer acting weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847571/sticky-footer-acting-weird)

Comment: Its not quite the same. The last question was answered. My content page is now expanding and pushing the footer down, but it is not sticking to bottom. Not the same problem as before.

Comment: Can you post the CSS of #footer please?

Comment: Sure, i now added it. :)

Comment: It's working in Chrome 21 on Win 7.

Comment: Not in my chrome. Try and zoom out all you can, please. Still acting normal?

Comment: You haven't told the footer to stay fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    clear: both;
    background-image: url("../images/footer_pattern.png");
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: upvoted for correct answer for sticky footer, but still didnt fix my problem. I think i am misunderstanding the concept sticky footer maybe, but what i asked for was to make the footer always stay at the bottom of the document, not nessecarily being shown on the screen. Sorry for my english.

Comment: That's not a sticky footer then. Just do it how you had it and put a 1000px min-width on the content div to push it down to the bottom. And also, my answer was correct for the question that you asked.

Comment: I didn't notice that before adding my comment, apologies. Just for clarification: a "sticky" element is one that is stuck to the page and, by definition, doesn't move.

Comment: i am actually trying that now. I seriously cant get it to work :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15096/discussion-between-thomas-teilmann-and-tom)

Answer (score 2):

For the website you are referring to, by extending the wrapper div, it will push the footer down.  Below is the modified css for wrapper.

```
  #wrapper
  {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      min-width: 1000px;
  }
```

Put 100% for the height instead of auto.

By making the wrapper height to 100%, it extends that div to the bottom of the window and pushes the footer down as well.

Another thing I would change is not make #footer float left.

Comment: Using `!important` is very bad style. Instead you should adjust your specificity so that the browser renders the style over others.

Comment: I added clarification to my answer.  I was referring to the #wrapper div, which is the div that surrounds the footer and rest of the page.  I got the css code from the website the original poster was referring to.

Comment: @chop, thanks for adding your clarification at the beginning of the answer. It makes more sense

Comment: Yes, but OP requires a sticky footer. Your solution would push the footer down beyond the display of the document in the window when the content is larger than the window. In order for it to be a sticky footer the footer must display at the bottom of the window regardless of the size of the content.

Comment: @Tom, according to your question your solution is the most accurate. (+1)  I chose to tackle the question a different way that would still put the footer at the bottom of the screen.  The reason for this was that the top of the footer background image has white like the main content.  I felt the webpage would look better without the gap in the background image of the main content.  I will follow the op more closely next time.

Comment: True, OP can edit the image to make it look neater. The answer I gave will work for OP but he seems to have disappeared! Also, does anybody actually use height: auto anymore?

Comment: Yeah it will be on the OP to make it look neater.  Maybe the OP got the answer he was looking for.

Comment: I hate it when people get the answer they want and then disappear without marking it as correct.

Comment: I up voted your answer, so others will pay more attention to until the OP can mark it correct.

Comment: i didnt try any of this yet, cause i just got home from work, and had to make som food. Just relax. Thx for your replies

Comment: upvoted cause this was really the answer, kind of, like i was looking for. I misunderstood the concept of sticky footer, so u marked toms answer as correct, for less confusion. Thx all

Comment: I figured you just had not had time to check the answer.  Glad you got what you needed.  (+1)